# rsync --compare-dest arg does not exist no matter what

Tags: rsync

I have these folders:

```
.
├── result
├── test
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   ├── file3
│   └── file4
└── test2
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    ├── file3
    └── file5
```

- `test` is the original folder.
- In `test2` some files are different, others are identical and others only exist in there.

I want to user rsync to copy in `result` only those files in `test2` that are newer that those on `test` or that doesn't exist on `test`.

I run any os the following, varying whether or not there's a `=` between `--compare-dest` and the name of the folder, whether or not the folder name has a trailing slash, or even inverting the parameters, just in case I'm missunderstanding what folder is compare-dest :

```
rsync -av --dry-run --itemize-changes --compare-dest=test2 test/ result/
rsync -av --dry-run --itemize-changes --compare-dest=test2/ test/ result/
rsync -arv --dry-run --itemize-changes --compare-dest test test2/ result/
rsync -arv --dry-run --itemize-changes --compare-dest test/ test2/ result/
```

All of them tell me:

```
--compare-dest arg does not exist: NAME_OF_EXISTING_FOLDER
```

- What am I doing wrong?
- What's the correct command I have ro issue to satisfy the requirement I explain at the beginning of this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man rsync`:

> If DIR is a relative path, it is relative to the destination directory.

You need:

```
rsync -av --dry-run --itemize-changes --compare-dest="$PWD"/test test2/ result/
```

Comment: I could give it three absolute paths then?

Comment: The parameters were inverted, I corrected it. The "older" folder must be indicated by `--compare-dest=` and the newer is the following parameter.